# Using ffmpeg, can I remove the color from an area of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

a TV station I watch has a very distracting logo, which is a semi transparent red square.

[image]

I can cover up the logo with the delogo filter like this: (Alas this introduces new distractions.)

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.TS -vf delogo=x=79:y=36:w=57:h=57:show=0 -t 120 -vcodec h264_qsv -b:v  12300k output.ts
```

Is there a way to use ffmpeg to **remove only the color** from the **area of the logo**?

Because if it was just gray, it wouldn't be that distracting and taking out the color would not introduce flickering artefacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution in cropping the video, turning it into black and white and then putting this as an overlay on itself.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input.ts" -filter_complex "[0] crop=57:57:79:39 [cr];[cr] hue=s=0 [cr2];[0][cr2] overlay=79:39" -map "[cr2]" -vcodec h264_qsv -b:v  12300k output.ts
```

Comment: This is the standard way to do it.